# Using functions as an argument in Bash

Tags: bash

I want to move a couple of files from point a to point b

but I have to manually specify

```
mv /full/path/from/a /full/path/to/b
```

but some times there are 20 files which I have to move manually. Instead of */full/path/form/a*, can't I just enter the a function which returns all the files which I want to move in my case;

*/full/path/to/b* is a directory, it's the target directory which all the files with extenstions mp3, exe and mp4 must go to:

```
mv ls *.{mp3,exe,mp4} /full/path/to/b
```

If I have to move a couple of files and I don't want to do it one by one, how can I optimize the problem?

Comment: If `/full/path/to/b` is a directory, then you can do simply `mv *.{mp3,exe,mp4} /full/path/to/b`. But I guess it's not exactly what you need. You haven't explained very well.

Comment: Which part didn't you understand ?

Comment: I don't understand what `/full/path/to/b` is supposed to be in the example of source files `*.{mp3,exe,mp4}`. If you added an example of manually renaming 2 concrete files, it would help.

Comment: no I don't want to rename I want to move, */full/path/to/b* is a directory, it's the target directory which all the files with extenstions mp3, exe and mp4 must go to

Comment: Moving and renaming are the same thing, synonyms. And the command I gave you in the first command will do what you need.

Comment: marton@linux-clwa:~> mv /home/marton/Свалени/*.{mp3,mp4} /backup/desktop/music/
mv: cannot stat ‘/home/marton/Свалени/*.mp3’: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat ‘/home/marton/Свалени/*.mp4’: No such file or directory

Comment: If you manually go at /home/marton/Свалени/ and type `ls *.mp3` do you get any results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `mv ls *.{mp3,exe,mp4} /full/path/to/b` in your question is not correct.
As pointed out in comments by @janos, the correct command is

```
mv *.{mp3,exe,mp4} /full/path/to/b
```

`mv` can complain about missing file if the file is really missing and/or the path is not accessible or is not valid.
As i can understand by your question description, if you go manually to the source path you can move the file to the desired directory.
Thus it seems that path is valid, and file exists.

In order `mv` to keeps complaining about `*.mp3 not found` (having a valid path and file) the only reason that pops up in my head is the Bash Pathname Expansion feature (enabled by default in my Debian).

Maybe for some reason this pathname expansion bash feature is disabled in your machine.

Try to enable this feature using command bellow and provide the correct command to mv and you should be fine.

```
$ set +f
```

PS: Check `man bash` about pathname expansion.

Comment: @harton you can undo by `set -f`. But if still not working pathname expansion could be active by the beginning and you don't need to disable it. In your source directory , do you get some output with `ls *.mp3`? Are there mp3 files in the directory?

Comment: @harton You can also apply `set -x` to bash prompt for debugging. With this `-x` option bash will inform you with messages starting with `+` for every step that is going to be executed.

Comment: Well, I thought it wasn't working because I was getting some errors, but these errors appeared because there were no files with mp3,exe and mp4 extension